# CMAKE configuration cannot find .h file with add_library & target_include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I currently have a problem with my CMake configuration for a small project I am working on. I wanted to reconfigure the project and move all header files into their own path. When trying to link the header file to the library I cannot include the file in my .cpp in any way (client_session or client_session_handler)

This is my project setup

```
    Headers
     - client 
        - client_session_handler.h
        - client_session.h
   src
     - client 
        - client_session_handler.cpp
        - client_session.cpp
        - CMakeLists.txt 
     main.cpp 
     - CMakeLists.txt 
   CMakeLists.txt
```

This is my client library setup

```
     add_library (
        client OBJECT
        client_session.cpp 
        client_session_handler.cpp )
     
     target_include_directories( client PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/headers)
```

This is my src cmake (There is other code but they haven't got any relevant .h files yet)

```
add_executable(rchat main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(client)
add_subdirectory(server)
add_subdirectory(helpers)


target_link_libraries(rchat
    PUBLIC
    client
    server
    helpers
    wsock32
    ws2_32
)
```

And finally my root CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(rchat LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Overall I can't seem to include the client headers at all in my code, so any help would be appreciated.

For includes I've tried "client/client_session.h" "client_session.h" & <client/client_session.h>

Cheers.

Comment: What does it mean that you "can't include"?

Comment: use command `tree` to provide information about project structure (less bug prone).

Comment: Sorry poor wording on my behalf, I meant it can't find the source file

Comment: if you have public repo we could clone then provide a link to it.

Comment: If you are not sure about your wording, then show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**. Also, whether directory with the header files is names as `Headers`, as shown in your tree, or as `headers`, as used in `target_link_directories` call?

Answer (score 0):

You only link your library but never add the library's header to your executable target. Next to your `target_link_libraries` you may want to add headers to use in your "client" code, like this:

```
target_link_libraries(rchat ..libraries go here..)
target_include_directories(rchat PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/client")
```